# How to mock a free function in python?

Tags: python, mocking

I have a python program with a global function that is painful to test (it needs a large dataset to work properly). *What is the best way to get around this while testing functions that call it?*

I've found that the following works (but it make me feel dirty to use it).

module foo:

```
def PainLiesHere():
  return 4; #guaranteed to be random
```

module test

```
import foo

def BlissLiesHere():
  return 5

foo.PainLiesHere = BlissLiesHere

# test stuff
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a perfectly fine way to do it.  As long as you know that `BlissLiesHere` does not change the overall behavior of the unit you are testing...

EDIT:

This is what is being done, under all the nice extras they provide, by different kinds of mocking libraries, such as [Mock](http://python-mock.sourceforge.net/), [Mox](http://code.google.com/p/pymox/), etc.