# Python unit testing functions by using mocks

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am fairly new to python development and I am not sure what will be the best way to inject mocks into a function for unit testing.

I have a function which looks like:

```
import exampleModule

def func():
    ls = createList()
    exampleModule.send(ls)
```

In the above code I want to mock `exampleModule.send` method.

Should I pass the method as argument to the function? Like:

```
def func(invokeMethod):
    ls = createList()
    invokeMethod(ls)
```

And in unit test I can pass the mock. But I do not want the caller to specify the invocation method.

What is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library by Michael Foord, which is part Python 3. It makes this kind of mocking very convenient. One way of doing it would be:

```py
>>> from mock import patch
>>> import exampleModule
>>>    
>>> def func():
...     ls = []
...     exampleModule.send(ls)
... 
>>> with patch('exampleModule.send') as send:
...     func()
...     assert send.called
```

Here we use it as a context manager. But you ca also use `patch` as a decorator. But there are more ways of using `mock` and it will probably meet all your needs in mocking/stubbing.

Answer (score 1):

Python supports functions as first class citizens, so you can override the implementation of a method for unit testing purposes.

[This approach basically shows you the way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154441/how-to-mock-a-free-function-in-python)

```
class Foo
   def thing_to_mock():
      really_expensive_stuff()

   def thing_to_test():
       i = 1 + 2
       thing_to_mock()
       return i

class FooTest
  def testingThingToTest():
       def mocker():
           pass
       toTest = Foo()
       toTest.thing_to_mock = mocker
       # assert here
```

Alternately, in Python 3.3 you can use the [built-in mocking support](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock).

Comment: The difference is, in my case, I am not testing a method (function in a class) but a high level function.